# How can I recover oracle database without new data?

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g

I have oracledb 11g. I setup archivelog mode on my server. There's my backup\recovery scenario:

```
rman TARGET SYS/pass@XE
RMAN> backup database plus archivelog;
```

After that I make changes to the data tables. Create new customer as example.
After that I execute in rman:

```
shutdown immediate;
startup mount;
restore database;
recover database; 
alter database open;
```

My server is started. I run my application and creater customer is there... Where's my mistake? I tried delete all dbf from db folder. And after restore database I saw my new customer. How can I restore a database without the data that was added to the database after the backup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You performed a complete recovery. Recovery uses the available archivelogs and redo logs as well.

To perform an incomplete recovery until the time that's before the changes, use:

```
recover database until time "to_date('2018-02-24 15:05:20', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')";
alter database open resetlogs;
```

Set the point of time as needed.

Answer (score 0):

You should do a Point in Time recovery to avoid the archivelogs with the Changs are Applied.